# HTML5 autocomplete (Work Like jquery autocomplete)

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I know how jquery autocomplete event works. But I want to use HTML5 autocomplete.

I found below code in HTML5 :

```
      <form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
            <input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">
            <datalist id="browsers">
                 <option value="Internet Explorer">
                 <option value="Firefox">
                 <option value="Chrome">
                 <option value="Opera">
                 <option value="Safari">
            </datalist>
            <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

Above code if I write "Chr" in "#browser" input field then it shows Chrome as suggestion. But If I write "me" in "#browser" input field then it does not show anything. (I expect it will show "Chrome" as suggestion Like Jquery autocomplete).

In Jquery :

If I take a list called Browsers Like

```
                    Browsers = ["Internet Explorer",
                               "Firefox",
                               "Chrome",
                               "Opera",
                               "Safari"];
```

If I use this list in autocomplete event of jquery, Then If I write "Chr" in inpur field then It shows Chrome as suggestion and also If I write "me" in "#browser" input field then it also shows "Chrome" as suggestion.

```
                    $("#browser").autocomplete({ 

                    });
```

I want to do this type of solution (Like jquery) in HTML5. I search a lot but can't get any solution or ideas. How can I do it? thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont think html5 gives such feature of elastic search in autocomplete